# BSImagePickerViewController for selecting videos from gallery in swift

Tags: ios, swift, ios9, uiimagepickercontroller, ios10

How to get videos from gallery using `BSImagePickerViewController`. I am already using it for selecting and fetching multiple images from gallery. But can it be used for videos also. No help found from google so far, already spend a day. Please guide.

Comment: Hi, You want to select multiple videos or mixture of pictures and videos?

Comment: @lee5783 mixture of pictures and videos

Comment: I posted my answer, pls check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just looked around and found this
https://github.com/mikaoj/BSImagePicker/issues/65

Seem like BSImagePicker does not support Video for now. You can use other library to pick both videos and pictures:

https://github.com/guillermomuntaner/GMImagePicker

https://github.com/zhangao0086/DKImagePickerController

I didn't use it before, but hope it can help you.

Comment: You should use GMImagePicker because it's written by Obj-C while DKImagePicker is written by Swift. If you are using Xcode 8 and Swift 3.0 you have to wait for next release (next month maybe)

Comment: DKImagePickerController correct option, but not easy to use, things not clear